# Unity Vuforia AR Project Apk not running in OnePlus nord

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I started learning AR 1 week ago. I started building marker-based AR projects using unity and vuforia. But after installing the project apk in my oneplus nord, app is just showing black screen after asking for camera permission.
I searched about this online and found that it may be occurring because of vulkan, so I deleted it! But the same problem is still there!
I have spent so much time searching for a fix to this issue, it would be of great if someone will help regarding this!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to Google removing ARCore support for 32-bit apps on 64-bit devices. You should switch the scripting backend in the project settings from *'Mono'* to *'IL2CPP'* and target both the *ARMv7* and *ARM64* architectures.

Comment: You can read more about the Google ARCore support changes here: https://developers.google.com/ar/64bit